# When is Doctrine 2 making errors with composite keys?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, composite-key

I was recently reading the [`Doctrine 2`'s best practices](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/best-practices.html) and was stopped by this:

> **25.3. Avoid composite keys**
>    Even though Doctrine fully supports composite keys it is best not to use them if possible. Composite keys
>   require additional work by Doctrine and thus have a higher probability
>   of errors.

What I don't get is this: if `"Doctrine fully supports composite keys"`, how can it make mistakes when dealing with such keys?

Therefore I would like to ask this question as a community wiki, hoping it will help us understand what the `"probability of errors"` are:

**Do you have examples to share showing situations you've ran into whereby `Doctrine 2` was not handling composite keys well/as it should?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my part I believe I've already ran into some issues with a very basic database schema containing a table which primary key is composed of 2 foreign keys:

[image]

**When I generate my models, the entity corresponding to the `product_i18n` entity isn't created**:

```
$ php doctrine-module.php orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Dbi\Entity\\" \
--from-database --force annotation module/Dbi/src/
Processing entity "Dbi\Entity\Locale"
Processing entity "Dbi\Entity\Product"

$ php doctrine-module.php orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations=1 \
module/Dbi/src
Processing entity "Dbi\Entity\Locale"
Processing entity "Dbi\Entity\Product"
```

Yet, I believe my [database schema](http://pastebin.com/Lhiw7Zpd) was properly created:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `locale_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_product_i18n_locale` (`locale_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_product_i18n_product` (`product_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_i18n_locale`
    FOREIGN KEY (`locale_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`locale` (`id` ),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_i18n_product`
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`product` (`id` )
```

Also, `Doctrine 2`'s `Schema Manager` shows that Doctrine seems to understand that relation perfectly (`var_dump` output altered to make it more concise: removing things such as `array`, `RECURSION`, `string`...):

```
$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
$sm = $em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager();
var_dump($sm->->listTables());

object(Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table)#290 (10) {
["_name":protected]=> "product_i18n"

["_indexes":protected]=>
  ["primary"]=>
    ["_columns":protected]=>
      [0]=> "product_id"
      [1]=> "locale_id"

["_fkConstraints":protected]=>
  ["fk_product_i18n_locale"]=>
  object(Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\ForeignKeyConstraint)#285 (9) {
    ["_localColumnNames":protected]=> "locale_id"
    ["_foreignTableName":protected]=> "locale"
    ["_foreignColumnNames":protected]=> "id"

  ["fk_product_i18n_product"]=>
  object(Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\ForeignKeyConstraint)#286 (9) {
    ["_localColumnNames":protected]=> "product_id"
    ["_foreignTableName":protected]=> "product"
    ["_foreignColumnNames":protected]=> "id"
```

Therefore I'm in a situation whereby I can query the schema for the `product_i18n` table, but can't interact with that table because the corresponding entity model wasn't generated.

**UPDATE:** as `user1136666` pointed out: the [known issues and limitations page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html) odes state the following:

> Although we state that we support composite primary keys that does not
>   currently include foreign keys as primary key columns.

The workaround is to define a surrogate key and add a unique constraint on the foreign keys, like so:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`product_i18n` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `description` TEXT NULL ,
  `created_at` DATETIME NULL ,
  `modified_at` DATETIME NULL ,
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `locale_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `fk_product_i18n_locale` (`locale_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_product_i18n_product` (`product_id` ASC) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE (`locale_id` , `product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_i18n_locale`
    FOREIGN KEY (`locale_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`locale` (`id` )
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_i18n_product`
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`product` (`id` )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Feature request: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1926**

Answer (score 2):

The problem on table product_i18n is it doesn't have primary key. Please try to set `product_id` and `locale_id` as composite primary key. Doctrine 2 will generate the entities. Primary key is required for doctrine 2 entity.

Comment: No it doesn't: `PRIMARY KEY (\`product_id\`, \`locale_id\`)`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see them. I think the real problem is use the primary keys as foreign keys. I have try without use them as foreign keys, and they work!

Please check here
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html

This case still in Doctrine 2 Limitations.

Comment: Indeed creating a surrogate key as primary key as a replacement of the primary key composed of foreign keys fixes the problem.